# jQuery alert when row with specific attribute is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have html table like below:

```
<table id='messagelist'>

  <tr id="rcmrowMTM" class="message selected" aria-selected="true">
    <td class="threads"><span class="threads"></span></td>
    <td class="subject" tabindex="0"><span class="fromto skip-on-drag"><span class="adr"><span title="test@example.com" class="rcmContactAddress">test@example.com</span></span>
      </span><span class="date skip-on-drag">Today 08:27</span><span class="subject"><span id="msgicnrcmrowMTM" class="msgicon status" title=""></span><a href="./?_task=mail&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_uid=13&amp;_action=show" onclick="return rcube_event.keyboard_only(event)"
      onmouseover="rcube_webmail.long_subject_title(this,1)" tabindex="-1"><span>test</span></a></span>
    </td>
    <td class="flags"><span class="flag"><span id="flagicnrcmrowMTM" class="unflagged" title="Not Flagged"></span></span><span class="attachment"><span class="attachment" title="With attachment"></span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="rcmrowNw" class="message">
    <td class="threads"><span class="threads"></span></td>
    <td class="subject"><span class="fromto skip-on-drag"><span class="adr"><span title="test@example.com" class="rcmContactAddress">test@example.com</span></span>
      </span><span class="date skip-on-drag">Sun 12:22</span><span class="subject"><span id="msgicnrcmrowNw" class="msgicon status" title=""></span><a href="./?_task=mail&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_uid=7&amp;_action=show" onclick="return rcube_event.keyboard_only(event)"
      onmouseover="rcube_webmail.long_subject_title(this,1)" tabindex="-1"><span>test</span></a></span>
    </td>
    <td class="flags"><span class="flag"><span id="flagicnrcmrowNw" class="unflagged" title="Not Flagged"></span></span><span class="attachment">&nbsp;</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Every time user click a row new class "selected" is added in `tr`.

What I want is to show alert if user click on a row and row has `title="With attachment"` like in last `td` of first row

Here is my code that I tried but it's not working.

```
$('#messagelist tr.selected').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).find("span[title|='With attachment']")) {
    alert('with attachment');
  }
});
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9enojseq/)

Comment: How is class added? If it is added after you look for `$('#messagelist tr.selected').on...` then there will never be any matches found

Comment: I think you are right. that's why it isn't working because it is added after.

Comment: is there any way that it start looking after selected class is added ?

Comment: Why not combine with the click event that adds the class?

Comment: actually I don't know how this class is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to combine the search for the "With attachment" in same event handler that adds the class.

Alternatively you can add a new click event listener to all rows... and check if the selected class exists

```
$('#messagelist').on('click', 'tr', function() {

    var $row = $(this);

   // slight delay while class is added
   setTimeout(function(){
      if($row.hasClass('selected') && $row.find("span[title|='With attachment']").length){
          alert('with attachment');
      }
   },50); 
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158238/javascript-alert-when-function-process-is-complete?noredirect=1#comment77285706_45158238

Answer (score 1):

Here you made mistake in your code

**Your Code**

```
$('#messagelist tr.selected').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).find("span[title|='With attachment']")) {
    alert('with attachment');
  }
});
```

**Updated Code**

```
$('.messagelist tr.selected').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).find("span[title|='With attachment']")) {
    alert('with attachment');
  }
});
```

`messagelist` is a `class` it's not a `id` So you should use `.messagelist` instead of `#messagelist`.

Hope this will helps you. :)

Comment: Still not a valid conditional. `if( $() )` will always be truthy

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. actually messagelist is a id.

Comment: No...use `length` to see if there are matches or not. `if ($(this).find("span[title|='With attachment']").length)`. The reason is `$(selector)` always returns an object...even when no matches are found and `if({})` is truthy

Comment: I think that is also a problem as class is probably added after `$('#messagelist tr.selected').on('click',..` is called and there would be no matches for that class at the time it is run

Comment: Yes i see your comment in the question. it is also possible. so @Snappy Can you please tell us how do you add that class or id.

Comment: is there any way that it start looking after selected class is added ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following snippet to:

```js
$('.messagelist tr.selected').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var span= $(this).find('span');
    var has_attachment
    $(span).each(function(){
       has_attachment = $(this).attr('data-title');      
    });

    if(has_attachment=="With attachment"){
        alert('with attachment');
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='messagelist'>

  <tr id="rcmrowMTM" class="message selected" aria-selected="true">
    <td class="threads"><span class="threads"></span></td>
    <td class="subject" tabindex="0"><span class="fromto skip-on-drag"><span class="adr"><span title="test@example.com" class="rcmContactAddress">test@example.com</span></span>
      </span><span class="date skip-on-drag">Today 08:27</span><span class="subject"><span id="msgicnrcmrowMTM" class="msgicon status" title=""></span><a href="./?_task=mail&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_uid=13&amp;_action=show" ><span>test</span></a></span>
    </td>
    <td class="flags">
      <span class="flag"><span id="flagicnrcmrowMTM" class="unflagged" title="Not Flagged"></span></span><span class="attachment">
      <span class="attachment" data-title="With attachment">
      </span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="rcmrowNw" class="message selected">
    <td class="threads"><span class="threads"></span></td>
    <td class="subject"><span class="fromto skip-on-drag"><span class="adr"><span title="test@example.com" class="rcmContactAddress">test@example.com</span></span>
      </span><span class="date skip-on-drag">Sun 12:22</span><span class="subject"><span id="msgicnrcmrowNw" class="msgicon status" title=""></span><a href="./?_task=mail&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_uid=7&amp;_action=show" 
      tabindex="-1"><span>test</span></a></span>
    </td>
    <td class="flags"><span class="flag"><span id="flagicnrcmrowNw" class="unflagged" title="Not Flagged"></span></span><span class="attachment">&nbsp;</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

i have a changed code a little but. in span i used `<span class="attachment" data-title="With attachment">` instead of `title=` as title is a reserved HTML tag and attribute.. `data-*` attributes are used for custom data handling in javascript or jQuery in most scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Checked for last TD and then it will check for title="With attachment" in span tag.

Also in your code messagelist is class instead of ID so you should use dot(.) in code.

```
$('.messagelist tr.selected').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).find('td:last').find("span[title|='With attachment']")) {
        alert('with attachment');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would `td:last` make a difference? If it can't be found anywhere in the row... narrowing it down to inside a specific `td` won't make any differnce

Comment: Also your conditional will always be truthy...even if no match is found

Comment: @charlietfl have you checked it? i tested the code before posting it . only for first row it is showing alert.

Comment: `if( $() )` is always truthy even when no selector matches found

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain more on this? I tested it and in second row last TD not matching specified text so it is not showing alert. Still I'll check again my code.

Comment: It is same as `if ( Object)` which is truthy ... **always** . Does row have `selected` class?