# Javascript alert when function process is complete

Tags: javascript

Here is Javascript code:

```
if (selected && this.env.contentframe && !list.multi_selecting)
this.preview_timer = setTimeout(function() {
  ref.msglist_get_preview();
  alert('done');
}, list.dblclick_time);
else if (this.env.contentframe)
  this.show_contentframe(false);
```

Here is `msglist_get_preview()` function code:

```
this.msglist_get_preview = function()
{
    var uid = this.get_single_uid();
    if (uid && this.env.contentframe && !this.drag_active)
      this.show_message(uid, false, true);
  };
```

And below id the `show_message()` function:

```
  this.show_message = function(id, safe, preview)
  {
    if (!id)
      return;

    var win, target = window,
      url = this.params_from_uid(id, {_caps: this.browser_capabilities()});

    if (preview && (win = this.get_frame_window(this.env.contentframe))) {
      target = win;
      url._framed = 1;
    }

url = this.url(preview ? 'preview': 'show', url);
this.location_href(url, target, true);
}:
```

What I want to alert when a function `ref.msglist_get_preview();` process is complete. I have tried but every time alert appears first then function loads.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that suggests `ref.msglist_get_preview()` is asynchronous ... any clue as to what it does and what it returns?

Comment: Have you considered placing the `alert('done');` at the end of the `msglist_get_preview` function?

Comment: You are using `setTimeout` as soon as the timeout is reaqched it will trigger the alert. Instead You should call it when the process is complete

Comment: @JaromandaX it loads message.

Comment: @Manish can you show me any example ? how can I do this ?

Comment: @Snappy - right, well, you need to wait for the message it loads to finish loading before executing `alert` - otherwise you will get the `alert` before the message it loads is finished loading as a message

Comment: We can't know what `ref.msglist_get_preview()` is or how it works, so we can't really help you. It must be asynchronous since the alert is happening first. You'll need to find out if there's some event you can listen to, or if you can edit the code of `ref.msglist_get_preview()`, just see what it does (or post the code of that function in your question so we can help).

Comment: we need to know what you are actually trying to achieve. We will be able to help you better if you can create a demo of your code.

Comment: @Clonkex in `msglist_get_preview()` function there is another function calling. and yest I can edit the code of `ref.msglist_get_preview()`

Comment: Ok so it's not an async function, but how are you determining when the "process is complete"? It looks like you're telling the browser to go to a new link, so are you expecting the alert to appear only once the page is loaded?

Comment: yes you are right and also after message content is loaded.

Comment: is there no solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout(function(){...}, 0) simply queues the code to run once the current call stack is finished executing. So the issue you are facing is because your >ref.msglist_get_preview(); is also doing asynchronous task and that's why it gets queued after the setTimeout and hence you get alert('done'); first and then your method execution.
Following is the example to explain the same:

```js
this.preview_timer = setTimeout(function() {
abc();
  alert('done');
}, 500);

function abc(){
 setTimeout(function(){
 alert('abc');
 },100) 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here alert('abc') will be executed after alert('done')

For your problem you can use the javascript [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises). Following code should solve for your problem:

```
 if (selected && this.env.contentframe && !list.multi_selecting)
this.preview_timer = setTimeout(function() {
  ref.msglist_get_preview().then(function(){
    alert('done');
  })
}, list.dblclick_time);
else if (this.env.contentframe)
  this.show_contentframe(false);

function msglist_get_preview() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         setTimeout((function() {
            alert('msglist_get_preview worked');
            resolve("Stuff worked!");
        }), 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the difference if I set timeout function right after I call `ref.msglist_get_preview();`. it would work the same and no need of extra code.

Comment: Here the point is to use the promise and call your alert method after ref.msglist_get_preview(); has been resolved. settimeout in ref.msglist_get_preview(); was just to show the purpose of further XYZ.. asynchronous operations happening in the method. You need not put settimeout in ref.msglist_get_preview(); method, then also it will work.

`function msglist_get_preview() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            //Your stuff....
            resolve("Stuff worked!");
    });
}`